# Re-Tag All Documents with a specific taxonomy

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, term-store

I have a taxonomy that exists and we would like to eliminate two of the subcategories. These categories have documents that have been tagged with that category and we would like them to be "re-tagged" as a new category which happens to be the parent category. I am trying to figure out the best approach to this, without programming if possible.

So in my situation the field "Loan Category" is a managed metadata field. Using this taxonomy as an example:

- Category A

  --SubCategory A

  --SubCategory B

  --SubCategory C
- Category B etc...

I would like to Delete Subcategory A and Subcategory C from the taxonomy as options and then retag the Loan Category field for all the documents in both those SubCategories as Category A.

Thanks in advance.